# Offline static code analysis similar to the LGTM online service

Tags: security, reporting, source-code, code-analysis

[LGTM](https://lgtm.com/) provides an online service to analyze source code of all major languages for security bugs and errors.

I am looking for a similar solution, which performs the tests while **the source code stays in the company**.

The solution I am looking for

- **may cost money** and
- **may be a closed source tool**
- must run on at least one of the OS: Microsoft Windows, or Linux
- should support at least C, C++ ideally also ASM.
- should report insecure libraries, if a CVE is public
- should report insecure style and patterns
- should report bugs, which can be found by simple static analysis